# Copy a tag value from website when it has double quotes in it

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to copy tag value from website but having trouble when double quotes are used directly in the tag. for example the website tag is as follows

```
<meta id="MetaDescription" name="DESCRIPTION" content="This is a title with "double quotes" in it " />
```

now in my program i am using the following lines to copy the content value.

```
string description = sitetag.Attributes["content"].Value.ToString();
```

but the description value after the above line is executed is "This is a title with ".

How do i copy the entire content value to a string?

PS: i don't have any control over the website i am trying to copy the content from, so i have to work with what i get.

I have however implemented a temporary fix which is as follows.

```
WebClient x = new WebClient();
string sourcedata = x.DownloadString(url);
string description = Regex.Match(sourcedata, @"\<meta id=\SMetaDescription\S name=\SDESCRIPTION\S content=\S(?<Description>[\s\S]*?)(?<ignore>\S) \/\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Description"].Value;
description = description.Trim();//remove the last space which i could not with a regular expression
```

Comment: did it work? (replacing with &quot;)

Comment: because I think it might show up like `This is a title with  &quot; double quotes  &quot; in it ` in which case you might need to use some function to decode the html entities from the string. In this case you could also do `.Replace("&quot;", "\"");`

Comment: No, as i said i cannot change anything in the website tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. It's not valid HTML as you imagine, the content actually **is** only "This is a title with " to begin with, so any HTML-Parser you use will fail. Fix the HTML.

Comment: This explains why -as is- it cannot work. I upvoted the other answer, though because it also suggests how to _make_ it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&quot;` html entity instead of double quotes. As @nvoigt already pointed out, you cannot use normal double quotes to display them as text in html, as they have a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace double quotes with `&quot;` which will be parsed as " (double quote) in html. here is how you can do it

```
string description = sitetag.Attributes["content"].Value.ToString().Replace("\"","&quot;");
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, that's too late. The Value will already contain only the part up to the first quotation marks. You really need to fix the HTML in the first place. It is not valid.

Comment: I agree with you @Fildor any non-alphanumeric characters should be avoided in meta. but solution refer as a workaround for the question asked :)